# Only one radio buttons being selected out of four questions

Tags: php, html, foreach, radio-button

I want to make a list of four questions and four options for each question. I have successfully fetched the questions with `foreach` loop but, radio buttons do not seem to work with `foreach` loop.

Eg: I chose one answer form the first question and jump to second, but if I select an answer for the second question, the selected option of the first questions gets deselected. I have tried changing values of options, that did not work, I tried using for loop inside the `foreach` loop and even that did not work.

Following is my code:

```
<form method="post" action="process/quiz.php">
<?php 

$quizList = $quiz->getQuiz(4);

if($quizList){

    foreach($quizList as $list){
        ?>
        <div class="row rowpadding">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2" id="panel1">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h5 class="panel-title">
                    <?php echo $list->title; ?>
                </h5>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body two-col">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="frb frb-danger margin-bottom-none">
                            <input type="radio" id="radio-button-1" name="ans1" value="<?php echo $list->option_A ?>">
                            <label for="radio-button-1">
                                <span class="frb-title"><?php echo $list->option_A ?> </span>
                                <span class="frb-description"></span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="frb frb-danger margin-bottom-none">
                            <input type="radio" id="radio-button-2" name="ans2" value="<?php echo $list->option_B ?>">
                            <label for="radio-button-2">
                                <span class="frb-title"><?php echo $list->option_B ?></span>
                                <span class="frb-description"></span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="frb frb-danger margin-bottom-none">
                            <input type="radio" id="radio-button-3" name="ans3" value="<?php echo $list->option_C ?>">
                            <label for="radio-button-3">
                                <span class="frb-title"><?php echo $list->option_C ?></span>
                                <span class="frb-description"></span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="frb frb-danger margin-bottom-none">
                            <input type="radio" id="radio-button-4" name="ans4" value="<?php echo $list->option_D ?>">
                            <label for="radio-button-4">
                                <span class="frb-title"><?php echo $list->option_D ?></span>
                                <span class="frb-description"></span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
        <?php
    }

}

?>


<div class="panel-footer rowpadding">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-block ">
                <span class="fa fa-send"></span>
                submit </button>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Is there anything that I am missing?

Comment: You will by this script generate multiple inputs with the same ID, which is invalid HTML.

Comment: @Qirel I have removed the id from the form but that did the same like it did when there was id.

Comment: Yeah, the ID doesn't matter, what does matter is that you keep using the same names for the same questions. See my answer below for the solution.

Comment: That was merely a comment - not the answer, @dearsina. ;-)

Comment: @Qirel, your comment is spot on, IDs _do_ matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you are re-using the names and the IDs of your inputs. Names and IDs have to be unique for the HTML to be valid, and to work as you intend it to. You can have the input-names as *HTML arrays* instead, and group by that.

Using the `$key` of the array, you can define a unique name for each your group of answers. We also use this to define the IDs of your elements, since they must be unique.

Changes made are,

- Include the `$key` in the loop
- Adding `-<?php echo $key; ?>` to all instances where you use the ID of the buttons (and the reference in the label), to ensure all IDs are unique
- Using `name="answer[<?php echo $key; ?>]"` instead of `ans1`, `ans2`, `ans3`, `ans4`. This ensures that only one radio button can be selected per answer, and that you have one array of answers, each element being the answer of one question.

```
foreach ($quizList as $key=>$list){
    ?>
    <div class="row rowpadding">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2" id="panel1-<?php echo $key; ?>">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h5 class="panel-title">
                        <?php echo $list->title; ?>
                    </h5>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body two-col">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="frb frb-danger margin-bottom-none">
                                <input type="radio" id="radio-button-1-<?php echo $key; ?>" name="answer[<?php echo $key; ?>]" value="<?php echo $list->option_A ?>">
                                <label for="radio-button-<?php echo $key; ?>">
                                    <span class="frb-title"><?php echo $list->option_A ?> </span>
                                    <span class="frb-description"></span>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="frb frb-danger margin-bottom-none">
                                <input type="radio" id="radio-button-2-<?php echo $key; ?>" name="answer[<?php echo $key; ?>]" value="<?php echo $list->option_B ?>">
                                <label for="radio-button-2-<?php echo $key; ?>">
                                    <span class="frb-title"><?php echo $list->option_B ?></span>
                                    <span class="frb-description"></span>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="frb frb-danger margin-bottom-none">
                                <input type="radio" id="radio-button-3-<?php echo $key; ?>" name="answer[<?php echo $key; ?>]" value="<?php echo $list->option_C ?>">
                                <label for="radio-button-3-<?php echo $key; ?>">
                                    <span class="frb-title"><?php echo $list->option_C ?></span>
                                    <span class="frb-description"></span>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="frb frb-danger margin-bottom-none">
                                <input type="radio" id="radio-button-4-<?php echo $key; ?>" name="answer[<?php echo $key; ?>]" value="<?php echo $list->option_D ?>">
                                <label for="radio-button-4-<?php echo $key; ?>">
                                    <span class="frb-title"><?php echo $list->option_D ?></span>
                                    <span class="frb-description"></span>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   <?php
}
```

Now, when you submit the form, the selected answers will be in an array where the name is `answer`. So you will have to do something like

```
foreach ($_POST['answer'] as $key=>$value) {
     // $key is the same key from the loop above
     // $value is the value of the selected radio button
}
```

Comment: How can I know the question of the answers coming in an array?

Comment: The `$key` in each array is the same. So `$_POST['answers'][0]` will be the answer to the question where `$key` in the loop with questions (`foreach ($quizList as $key=>$list) {`) was 0. If you define that key to be the ID of the question, you then have the ID of the question in both the answer-loop and the question-loop.

Answer (score 1):

Radio buttons are tied together by name. In your `foreach()`, you keep repeating the same names for each set of question answers. (You're also repeating the same ID, which is bad form, but won't break your script).

You need to restructure your radio buttons so that each group of buttons (that belong together) have the same name. And that name has to be unique per group.

A simplified example:

```
<form>
  <p>These belong together, and all have the name "gender":</p>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>

  <p>These belong together, and all have the name "team":</p>
  <input type="radio" name="team" value="blue"> Blue<br>
  <input type="radio" name="team" value="red"> Red<br>
</form>
```

Comment: is there any possible way to do it with foreach loop? Because looping, the radio buttons were working perfectly fine.

Comment: Yes, absolutely, I believe there is already an answer to this, so have a look there.

Answer (score 1):

An even more simplified answer

```
foreach($quizList as $key => $list){ ?>
 <form>
    <input type="radio" id="radio-button-1" name="answer[<?php echo $key;?>]" value="<?php echo $list->option_A ?>"> <!-- answer_0 -->
    <input type="radio" id="radio-button-1" name="answer[<?php echo $key;?>]" value="<?php echo $list->option_B ?>"> <!-- answer_0 -->
</form>
```

Then in php you should get something like this:

```
 $_POST['answer'] = [
       '0' => 'foo'
       //'1' => 'biz' ....
  ];
```

**With Ajax**

One note with numbered keys.  IF you use AJAX (if not you can basically ignore this) you may lose numeric indexes when converting to and from JSON, for example imagine we expect this:

```
  $_POST['answer'] = [
       '0' => 'foo'
       '2' => 'biz' ....
  ];
```

When that is encoded in Json it will likly be something like this (where did the keys go)

```
  '{"answer":["foo", "biz"]}`
```

Then when PHP converts that back we have lost our keys. And we we'll have something like this:

```
  $_POST['answer'] = [
       0 => 'foo'
       1 => 'biz' ....
  ];
```

This is also true of any array function that doesn't preserve keys, `sort` etc.  The easy solution here is to just prefix the key with something like `a` or `_` even.  Then they will be strings and translate to objects in the JSON.  In PHP you could still match these like this:

```
  if("a$id" == $post_id){}

  if(substr($post_id,1) == $id){}

  //remove all prefixes
  print_r(array_combine(preg_replace('/^a/', '', array_keys($answers)),$answers));

  //it feels wrong but if you have to append you can do this
   var_dump((int)'2a' == 2); //true so your key would be 2a because how PHP converts strings to ints.
```

And so on.

Hope it helps!